# Select Case wrong Output

Tags: excel, vba, select, case

So I am trying to get my macro to analyse some data for me in a sheet. The data is on cells B2 to B6 and is numbers between 0 and 4 (decimals).

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with the code, it works perfectly fine with a different set of conditions on different cells as I've shown below

This code works :

```
Sub Salmondepthoutlet()
    Dim score As Double, result As String
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long

i = 0

With Sheets("Vertical")
    For Each Rng In .Range("B7:B16")
        score = Rng.Value
        Select Case score
            Case Is >= 0.15
                result = "1"
            Case 0.11 To 0.14
                result = "0.6"
            Case 0.08 To 0.1
                result = "0.3"
            Case Is <= 0.07
                result = "0"
        End Select
        .Range("B26").Offset(i).Value = result
        i = i + 1
    Next Rng
End With
End Sub
```

But this code doesn't (nothing appears in B21 for the output & results are wrong for the others)

```
Sub Salmonvelocityoutlet()
Dim score As Double, result As String
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long

i = 0

With Sheets("Vertical")
    For Each Rng In .Range("B2:B6")
        score = Rng.Value
        Select Case score
            Case Is >= 3
                result = "0"
            Case 2.99 To 2.6
                result = "0.3"
            Case 2.59 To 2.09
                result = "0.6"
            Case Is <= 2
                result = "1"
        End Select
        .Range("B21").Offset(i).Value = result
        i = i + 1
    Next Rng
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help & time

Comment: Should `.Range("B2:B6")` be `.Range("B7:B16")`

Comment: No it's the right range, got it wrong originally in the question edited now.

Comment: Your edited code [works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S4zwf.jpg).  What values do your cells have? (Can you copy/paste some data)?  Note that it will likely never return a value in `B21`, since you're offsetting by `i` cells.

Comment: @BruceWayne `i` starts at 0 so it should start in B21 then increment from there.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Yah, I couldn't tell from OP's post whether they realize it will not always be in `B21`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are running into problems with results "on the margin" (essentially rounding errors) due to the fact that Excel uses the IEEE standard for double precision math, and you are using decimal values. With what you have written, certain values may never even show up.  Unless you want to specifically exclude certain values within the range 0 to 3, I would suggest re-writing your select statement to:

```
Select Case score
        Case Is >= 3
            result = "0"
        Case Is >= 2.6
            result = "0.3"
        Case Is > 2
            result = "0.6"
        Case Is > 0  'Or Case Else
            result = "1"
    End Select
```

Comment: That works great thank you. One last question, how do I add a clause so that if the cell is empty, the result isn't one but an empty cell? I've tried         Case Else result = "" but it doesn't work and I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: I've also attempted Case "" Exit Sub but that just gives me a value of 0, I need no value.

Comment: @Lilou  I cannot reproduce your problem.  Adding `Case Else: result = ""` after `Case Is > 0` statement results in an empty cell being returned if the tested cell is empty.  You will need to provide more context.

Comment: Hi Ron, It was because my variable score was a double not a variant, works now.